# QGIS 2.10 for OS X dos not start on OS X 10.9.5

Tags: qgis, installation, osx

I have installed QGIS 2.10.1-1 from Kyngchaos.com following the provided instructions and installation requirements.
The install process of GDAL Complete 1.11, Matplotlib and QGIS (in this order) was ok, apparently.
Then, when I launch the QGIS software, after the splash screen the program crashes without any message during the loading of the GUI.

What is missing?

Comment: Do you have the requirements installed? http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis

Comment: in particular the Python modules matplotlib and numpy ?